# Where to save uploaded images in "asp.net core web api with react" spa template and serve images to client?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core-webapi

I start a project with asp.net core web API with react(spa template) and want to upload Images to server (for example user avatar) and then show images in client app.

There isn't any problem to upload but my question is where to save uploaded images?

There is location of static files in ConfigureServices in startup.cs

```
// In production, the React files will be served from this directory
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
{
    configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build";
});
```

and in react I know I must use "public" folder for statics files but the problem is in development and debugging with vs 2019 files dynamically adds to "ClientApp/build/public" does not showing in browser and I will get error 404.

Am I must handle static files like .jpg with asp.net core? or there is another option?

I expect to retrieve image by url like this: "https://{sitename}/img/example.jpg"

Comment: Asp.net core ships with StaticFiles middleware, have a look at app.UseStaticFiles() for serving them and for saving files, you can get the path of the project from IHostingEnvironment interface which you can inject in the controllrr constructor or directly in the save action. Let me know if you need a more hands on example.

Comment: there is not any problem on saving. actually I'm using IHostingEnvironment to save files to "ClientApp/build/public" folder with my static files for react js files.
 the problem is when debugging in development cant access image by url.
currently searching for configuring app.UseStaticFiles. if you can please provide an example for app.UseStaticFiles configuration.
thank you

Comment: Now I'm not very good with react, but if your app is working there's a good chance that StaticFiles middleware is working, now since you want to access the file from {siteUrl}/img. You will have to save your images inside the public/img folder, that's because the // means that you are refererring to the public folder

Answer (score 1):

in `startup.cs` under configure you should do this :

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath,"images")),
    RequestPath = "/img"
});
```

and then in your c# you can access images like this:

```
 Path.Combine("img","example.jpg")
```

and in client side you can access images like this:

```
<img src="/img/example.jpg"/>
```

and with url you like this:

```
https://{sitename}/img/example.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
  FileProvider = new 
  PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), 
  "static")),
  RequestPath = "/images"
});
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

Namespace

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
```

suppose you have static directory where you save all your images. You can access them by following URL.

```
https://localhost:7142/images/example.jpg
```

Make sure to use the server url in my case it is https://localhost:7142

if you are using SPA then to load image through front end url you need to add

```
 const context = [
  "/static"
];
```

to your **setupProxy.js**